# query inside/outside React context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an existential question about react context.
Let's say I have a component that uses useEffect to make call my back-end and get some data. then useState set it inside the context, it works fine, but what if I use useEffect and call my back-end inside the context and then just read data in the component. what you think which one is more "accurate"

for example

old method

```
context.Js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const defaultValue = {someState};

export const SomeContext = React.createContext();
export const SomeProvider = ({ someId }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(defaultValue);

    setData = (data) => { do some logic then setState(data)}

    const value = {
        ...state,
     setData
    };

    return <SomeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SomeContext.Provider>;
};

index.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SomeContext, SomeProvider } from "context/SomeContext";
import { getById } from "services";

const Layout = ({ someId }) => {
const { data, setData } = useContext(GroupContext);
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            //getById call my back-end to get some data
            getById(someId).then(setData)
        }, [])

return <Component />
    }
export default props => {

const providerProps = {
    someId,
};

return (
    <GroupProvider {...providerProps}>
        <Layout activeTab={activeTab} {...props} />
    </GroupProvider>
);
};
```

new method

```
context.Js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getById } from "services";

const defaultValue = {someState};

export const SomeContext = React.createContext();
export const SomeProvider = ({ someId }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(defaultValue);

    useEffect(()=>{
        //getById call my back-end to get some data
        getById(someId).then(setState)
    }, [])

    const value = {
        ...state,
    };

    return <SomeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SomeContext.Provider>;
};

index.js
import { SomeContext, SomeProvider } from "context/SomeContext";

    const Layout = ({ }) => {
    const { data } = useContext(GroupContext);

return <Component />
    }


export default props => {

const providerProps = {
    someId,
};

return (
    <GroupProvider {...providerProps}>
        <Layout activeTab={activeTab} {...props} />
    </GroupProvider>
);
```

};

something like this

Comment: What do you mean by inside the context? Can you provide code showing components hierarchy for this use case?

Comment: this is a very approximate example